# Downloading more than one file from a web server

Tags: vb.net

VS 2008 SP1

I am using the web client to download a file. Which works ok.

However, now I have to download many and the number of files to download will change everyday.

I am not sure how I can get the web client to know which files have been downloaded or not? I was thinking of using a for loop to download each file. But I will never know how many there are to download?

The web client could download the same file twice?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
Private Sub btnStartDownload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
 Dim client As New WebClient()
 AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_DownloadProgressChanged
 AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client_DownloadFileCompleted

 ' Starts the download
 client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("UrlFilePath"), "DownloadPath")

 btnStartDownload.Text = "Download In Process"
 btnStartDownload.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download multiple files with one HTTP request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041542/how-to-download-multiple-files-with-one-http-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a [multi-part content type and BinaryWrite](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_multiple-files-one-request/) but my understanding is that browser support for that content type is spotty at best.

[How to download multiple files with one HTTP request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041542/how-to-download-multiple-files-with-one-http-request)

Answer (score 1):

We have previously built a system that required the the user download many files. The way we solved it was to zip the files on the server side then download it as a single file.

Comment: I can't really do that. The users want all the individual files downloaded and don't want to have to unzip them.

Comment: Are these internal users? Will they always be on an internal network? Do they have Office enterprise licences?

Comment: These are user that will install our software and download the updates through the Internet.