# Which browsers support data URIs and since which version?

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

Which browsers support [data URIs (RFC 2397)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) and since which version?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Data URI support status for the five major browsers:

- Chrome, supported in all versions
- Firefox, supported in all versions
- Internet Explorer, [supported since 8.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(VS.85).aspx) (however, [some restrictions apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs))
- Opera, [supported since 7.2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs)
- Safari, supported in all versions

Additionally [this trick](http://weston.ruter.net/2009/05/07/detecting-support-for-data-uris/) can be used to detect data URI support.

Comment: IE and Edge support the Data URIs only for the<img> tag's src attribute. They don't support it for say href attribute of the <a> tag or data attribute of the <object> tag.

Comment: Is this webpage incorrect/incomplete, then? http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri It is the first result when I Google "data uri browser support".

Answer (score 5):

It also appears to work on many mobile browsers now.  [This is the best list I've found](http://caniuse.com/datauri).

Answer (score 2):

Every browser on this Earth supports Data URI's except the **__** . (You guessed it right - IE 6,7)