# why I can't view the <p:graphicimage> while use view as scope?

Tags: spring-mvc, primefaces, scope

Guys When I  using view as scope.I can't preview the `<p:graphicImage>`.But if i use session as scope i can view the `<p:graphicImage>`. why ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser fetches images in another connection so the view scoped bean will be instantiated multiple times. The urls of the images will also be different and thus the images will not be shown in the browser.

The `p:graphicImage` will work with any other scope IIRC. There are numerous other questions asked about this subject, like this one: [How to use p:graphicImage with StreamedContent within p:dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304967/how-to-use-pgraphicimage-with-streamedcontent-within-pdatatable)

Answer (score 0):

I used inlined images to get around the problem (which is ideal if you're real-time generating the images, but a bad choice if they're pre-existante).

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838464/convert-byte-to-base64-string-for-data-uri) for more info.