# Java send byte[] to base64Binary in XSL transformation

Tags: java, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm trying to send a byte array from java code as a parameter to xslt. I declared the type as base64Binary in XSL and set the byte array as parameter. I get an error that the supplied value is byte. What am I doing wrong?

**XSL:-**

```
<xsl:param name="attachmentBytes" as="xs:base64Binary" />
```

**Java code:-**

```
byte[] bytes = "SAMPLE".getBytes();
transformer.setParameter("attachmentBytes", bytes);
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(sourceDocument), new StreamResult(targetStream));
```

**Error code:**
XPTY0004: Required item type of value of variable is xs:base64Binary;  supplied value has item type xs:byte

Comment: Do you need to supply a String instead? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838464/convert-byte-to-base64-string-for-data-uri

Comment: I changed it to base 64 encoded String using Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes); ends up in "Cannot convert value class net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceExtent of type xs:base64Binary to
  class net.sf.saxon.value.Base64BinaryValue"

Comment: Added the tag "saxon": type conversions depend on which XSLT processor you are using, and your comment shows that you are using saxon.

Comment: Please note, you also raised the same question at https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/6128. It's generally bad form to raise the same question on more than one forum unless one of them gives you no answer.

Answer (score 1):

`XSLT` is waiting for a `base64binary` but you're giving a `byte`, **if you dont mind the type**, just change:

```
<xsl:param name="attachmentBytes" as="xs:base64Binary" />
```

by

```
<xsl:param name="attachmentBytes" as="xs:byte" />
```

If you want to mantain the base64binary check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19996331/3850595) that shows how to convert from `byte[]` to `base64binary`, basically:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("data:image/png;base64,");
sb.append(StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.encodeBase64(imageByteArray, false)));
contourChart = sb.toString();
```

Comment: In fact, I was sending a byte array returned using String.getBytes(). i tried the snippet above. Since this is an xsl transformation, i removed the "data:image/png;base64," and tried encoding it. However it ends up in "Cannot convert value class net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceExtent of type xs:base64Binary to
  class net.sf.saxon.value.Base64BinaryValue".

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce the problem. The following JUnit test completes successfully:

```
public void testBase64BinaryParam() {
        try {
            String xsl = "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"2.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">\n" +
                " <xsl:param name='in' as='xs:base64Binary' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'/>\n" +
                " <xsl:template match='/'>\n" +
                "   <out><xsl:value-of select='string($in)'/></out>\n" +
                " </xsl:template> \n" +
                "</xsl:stylesheet>";
            TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer =
                tfactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsl)));
            byte[] bytes = "SAMPLE".getBytes();
            transformer.setParameter("in", new net.sf.saxon.value.Base64BinaryValue(bytes));
            transformer.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
            transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsl)),
                new StreamResult(System.out));
        } catch (Exception err) {
            fail();
        }
    }
```

The output of the above is

```
<out>U0FNUExF</out>
```