# Javascript open content type

Tags: javascript, xml, excel, content-type

In javascript I have a string, containing an SpreadsheetML file (excel xml)

I want to open a new window, and write this data to it, but have it open as excel.

Can I do that from javascript?

Comment: a true XLXS file is a zip archive containing several XML zipped files. Do you actually have a string contaning the binary of an XLSX files, or just a XML content of an Excel-XML worksheet data?

Comment: Yes, I was mistaken, it was actually SpreadsheetML, not xlsx.

Comment: you should aslo drop the xlsx tag...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with a [data URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Uri),. First, encode the document as [base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript). Then, use the following URL as source of your window:

```
var mtype = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
var url = 'data:' + mtype + ';base64,' + base64data;
window.open(url);
```

This will require a [modern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765342/which-browsers-support-data-uris-and-since-which-version) [browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri).

Comment: Note, this will NOT work in IE. According to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs, Internet Explorer 8 and above only supports data URIs for images in CSS, <link>, and <img>. So IE doesn't understand the content-type.

Comment: Yes, as of IE 11, there's no full support for data URIs. Follow the [link in the answer](http://caniuse.com/datauri) to see current browser support. IE [does support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx) the content-type parameter, just not the content type for spreadsheet documents (in data URIs).