# PHP: Obtaining image from other PHP script

Tags: php, html, image, web

I'm having kind of controller http://samplesite.com/application/getimage  written in php. It is a simple script that responds to GET with some parameters. According to these parameters I find an image in database (image is stored there as a BLOB) and I return it as follows:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
```

`$image` is a BLOB of image obtained from database. 
When I open this URL http://samplesite.com/application/getimage/?id=200  my web browser displays an image.

Now I want to display this image inside a table in another php script. I want to perform it like

`echo "<img src="http://mysite.com/application/getimage/?id=200" ...some params here... />";`

but 
this approach does not work. It displays no image or makes other problems.

What approach should I choose to make this work? I'm new to php normally work with Java EE. Thanks very much.

**EDIT:**
Of course there should be inside the echo \" and not only ". But this approach that I wrote here works fine. Problem was in syntax, I had one extra ).

Comment: using a return rather than an echo might be the first step.

Comment: You need to escape the `"` speech marks within the string you're echoing, e.g. `echo "<img src=\"http....`

Comment: @sjmarshy: Or... not? That wouldn't work.

Comment: @Reshi: My answer works, I know, I'm using it.

Comment: @Pudge601 It might be easier to use `'` for the string delimiter, and use concatenation (`.`) when necessary. I prefer the template approach, though, `non-PHP code <?php echo htmlspecialchars($value); ?> non-PHP code` as it preserves the markup for syntax highlighting and outline views.  It can be written without problems as `<?= htmlspecialchar($value); ?>` from PHP 5.4 on. The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/) also recommends it. The safer [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) with the proper character encoding can be automated with a template engine or MVC approach.

Comment: @LightningDust See [Which browsers support data URIs and since which version?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1766942/855543) and [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/855543) as to why it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Passing a PHP file AS an image (not recommended)**

Your issue is that you haven't escaped speech marks, replace:

```
echo "<img src="http://mysite.com/application/getimage/?id=200" ...some params here... />";
```

With:

```
echo "<img src='http://mysite.com/application/getimage/?id=200' ...some params here... />";
```

or:

```
echo "<img src=\"http://mysite.com/application/getimage/?id=200\" ...some params here... />";
```

However, there is a far better way to do this:

**Using image BLOBs properly**

You're on the right track -- you can use an image BLOB instead of a file to put an image inline, but there's a little more work to it. First, you need to `base64_encode` the blob before you pass it. You should omit the header as you're passing text, not an image:

```
echo base64_encode($image);
```

Next, you need to set up the image tag like this, declaring that you are using data, the mime type and finally including the output of your `getimage` script as declared by [RFC2557](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2557.txt):

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php include('http://mysite.com/application/getimage/?id=200'); ?>"/>
```

That should fix the issue.

Comment: Don't personally see the advantage of the latter solution over what he's currently doing. In fact, that seems like a pretty bad idea in most situations

Comment: the problem is when i try this that /getimage does not display anything. It must display an image. the <img src=\" does not work no matter f i use base64 or not. It displays that there is supposed to be an image but no image is displayed (it displays only frame).

Comment: −1. There is absolutely *no* good reason to use the not well supported `data:` URI scheme here. If the application prints raw data to stdout, you can simply use the application URI as value of the `src` attribute. Calling the simpler, more compatible approach “not recommended” is *utter nonsense*.

Comment: the problem obviously is that im echoing <img  ... doing echo "<img src='' etc />";

Comment: See [Which browsers support data URIs and since which version?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1766942/855543) and [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/855543).