# PDF embedding in IE10 not working with <Object> tag

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer, pdf

I am using Angularjs and REST to display and retrieve PDF. It works fine in all the browsers except IE. I am using IE10. Getting an error message "Access Denied". Need some help . Is there any way to fix this problem. I am using Object tag in the html page for displaying pdf.

HTML source:

```
<object  data="{{content}}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 700px;"></object>
```

Js source:

```
$http.get(url,{ responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(function(response){

                 var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                 fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                 content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);

                });
```

Googled a lot but couldn't get a proper solution. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From here:

https://forums.adobe.com/message/5262172

Which leads here:

https://superuser.com/questions/561036/unable-to-open-ie-10-in-32-bit-mode

"This occurs because the TabProcGrowth registry entry is set to 0, meaning tabs are set to run in the same process as the manager process (64-bit), rather than opening a new process for each tab (32-bit). You can fix this by changing the registry entry here:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth

Set it to something greater than 0, restart IE, and you should see normal behavior resume (and your add-ons should work again). "

Comment: Thanks for the reply but there is no TabProcGrowth under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main in the registry in my system :(

Comment: create it and restart, it should fix it

Comment: Tried but it did not fix the problem

Comment: I have tried all the possible approaches like using iframes, embed tag etc .None worked for me . With Iframe i am not getting any error msg and i can see the request and response but it is showing blank :( . I am wondering if others have also faced the same issues with Angularjs, PDF and IE combination

Comment: is it actually uses datauri: for the PDF data? If so then you should be aware of limitations for inline data in IE, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765342/which-browsers-support-data-uris-and-since-which-version