# How can I access a file which is out of document root?

Tags: php, path

Here is my code:

```
// captcha.php

<?php
session_start();

  $min=0;
  $max=9;
  $captcha_token='';
  for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){$captcha_token .= rand($min,$max).' ';}
    $_SESSION['captcha'] = str_replace(" ","",$captcha_token);


$im = imagecreatetruecolor(110, 34);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 245, 245, 245);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 80, 80, 80);
imagestring($im, 8, 15, 9, $captcha_token, $text_color);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

And I use it like this:

```
<img src="../../files/captcha.php" class="captcha_pic" alt="Captcha" />
```

It works as well. As you know, that is a http request. I mean I can open that image like this:

```
http://localhost/myweb/files/captcha.php
```

---

Now I want to change the place of `file` directory and put it out of the document root. So I cannot access `captcha.php` through a http request. I have to use absolute path to get it.  How?

Noted that this doesn't work:

```
<?php
    $img = include __DIR__ . "/../../files/captcha.php";
?>
<img src="<?=$img?>" class="captcha_pic" alt="Captcha" />
```

Comment: `<img src="$img" ...` won't work since it's not within `<?php ... ?>`, so `$img` will not get substituted by its value.

Comment: @pgngp I was a typo. Edited. Thanks

Comment: If I remember correctly, `__DIR__` doesn't have a trailing `/`. Did you try using `$img = include __DIR__ . "/../../files/captcha.php";` instead?

Comment: @pgngp You're right, but look, I've tested *(almost)* all paths. So the problem is something else. I guess the problem is related to initializing `include()` to a variable.

Comment: <img src="some img: .... > is going to get the browser to request the image file. It seems that the request cant get to the directory the webserver is allowing the browser request to get to. Can your do a GET for this image?. If this is the case, you could have the browser ask PHP to get the file for you, and return it in the response. Some thing like, http://site?action=getFile&file=captacha.php.

Comment: You won't be able to specify a path outside the document root in a tag. If you want to feed a file from **below** the root, you will need to use [readfile()](http://us.php.net/readfile) with proper calls to `header()` prior.

Comment: Does `../../` put you below root? If so, see my comment above. Also, you cannot use absolute paths in a url (http request) - they are for server side file reference only. If you want to specify the full path, you are starting with `http://localhost` then add your path. e,g `http://localhost/path/to/files/captcha.php`

Answer (score 1):

You could place your functionality in a file, that you then include and use to generate a base64 encoded data image:

```
<?php
function createBinaryImageCaptcha($text) {
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(110, 34);
    $red = imagecolorallocate($im, 245, 245, 245);
    imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 80, 80, 80);
    imagestring($im, 8, 15, 9, $text, $text_color);
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($im);
    imagedestroy($im);

    return ob_get_clean();
}

function createDataImage($binary) {
    return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($binary);
}
```

Then require above that you can place where you like.  To use:

```
$img = createDataImage(createBinaryImageCaptcha('helloearth'))
?>
<img src="<?= $img ?>" alt="captcha text">
```

Bear in mind that not all browsers support data uris for images.

[Which browsers support data URIs and since which version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765342/which-browsers-support-data-uris-and-since-which-version)

And please consider captcha accessibility.