# Download multible files with JavaScript(one Download)

Tags: javascript, flash, client

I generate a HTML page with VB.Net which stores several pinks to files. These links are formatted with JavaScript looking like the Windows-Explorer with folders and files. The problem: There are only download links for the files, not for Folders. A folder can contain Subfolders ,a List of Files or a combination of both. So if I want to download a folder, I have to click manually on every file-link. I have not the possibility to insert PHP or another Server-side language.
my question now is:
Is there a client side way to Download them by click on a Folder? I prefer Javascript but If it isn't possible Flash will be ok also.

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041542/how-to-download-multiple-files-with-one-http-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is, link the folders to a special ASPX file. In this file, just create a ZIP with all the files inside it, and make the browser download that ZIP file. I think it's the easy way to accomplish what you are trying to.

With Javascript you could open several windows, one with each file downloaded. But I don't think it will please your users.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in Javascript and as far as I can tell, theres no way to do it in Flash either. A server-side zip is going to be your only way.