# Force multiple file download with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, download

I am trying to write a little script to backup all my localhost databases at once in seperate files. Currently my script does the backup part but does the download in one file. (So i get something like 30MB information_schema_backup.sql ) What i want is db_name_backup.sql for each database. Here is my code.

```
<?

    function backup_dbs()
    {
        global $db_name;
        global $dosyaadi; //dosyaadi means filename.
        $return='';

        /*
            Backup Part Here;
            I can share if anyone needs.
            I will post this on my blog anyway.
        */

        //save file
        $dosyaadi=$db_name.'-backup-'.time().'.sql';
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=$dosyaadi");
        echo $return;
    }

        $db_host = 'localhost';
        $db_user = 'root';
        $db_pass = '';

        $db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);

        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db);
        mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $db); 
        mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_general_ci'", $db); 

        $res = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $db_name =  $row['Database'];
            mysql_select_db($db_name, $db);
            backup_dbs();
        }
    die();
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not possible within the bounds of HTTP to offer more than one file for download in a single transaction. You will need to generate files, store them locally, and provide links to the individual files. Or you could zip them up into a single file and offer that for download - which is probably not a bad idea anyway as raw SQL will probably compress down to a considerably smaller package than the raw data.

Comment: Another option instead of downloading the whole stuff via HTTP is to store the backups on the server and load the files to your local machine or wherever using SSH or FTP. Or you can pack them using TAR or ZIP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download multiple files with one HTTP request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041542/how-to-download-multiple-files-with-one-http-request)

Comment: There is an apache mod called [`spdy`](http://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/) that will allow multiple downloads - but its quite unstable ... why not use a ZIP ?

Comment: @ManseUK Thankyou very much. That'll pass the time til GTA5 comes out...

Comment: @DaveRandom lol whats the release date ?? ;-)

Comment: @Jon, I don't think this question is duplicate since the files i try to download are the files i generate on the air. So that is not quite link you provide.

Comment: @DaveRandom and feeela, So do i have to save all those backups as file first then zip them? Because if so i have to search about zipping them.

Comment: @Mustafa: It makes absolutely no difference. Your problem has to do with limitations of the HTTP protocol, not where the files come from.

Comment: I seriously hope you emptied your password above and you arent actually using root w no password! lol