# How to serve multiple blobstore files at a time in google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I know how to serve a single blobstore file, I used below code snippet:

```
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(key);
response.setContentType("mime");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, response);
```

But I want to download multiple files at a time. ie. request handler will serve multiple files at a time. I used this code but didn't work

```
for (String key : blobKeyCollection) {
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(key);
response.setContentType("mime");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, response);
}
```

Instead serving multiple files, it responsed one file only. So, I want to know how to achieve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen anywhere else that you can download multiple files at the same time with a single request?

Answer (score 5):

Browsers do not support multi-files download - the [only option is to zip files together and download the zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041542/how-to-download-multiple-files-with-one-http-request).

To do this you can use [Files API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) to read multiple files and [zip them up](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/8362).

Comment: Yah, I don't think its Blobstore's fault that it can't serve multiple files