# How to specify multipart HTML code so it's downloaded with 1 GET request

Tags: mime, multipart

I want to render a web page using content type Multipart, but my sniffer logs always show multiple GET requests for the images on the web page.

Here is my test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>multipart/form-data</title>
    <header><h2>Testing multipart/form-data</h2></header>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="multipart/related; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
</head>
<body>
    Text outside the &lt;form&gt; tag.
    <form 
        enctype="multipart/form-data"   
        method="POST"
        action="/php/showPostGet.php" >   <!-- The enctype attribute can only be used if method="post". -->

        Text inside the &lt;form&gt; tag.<br />
        <input type="submit" value='TEST'/><br>
        <form enctype="multipart/text/plain">
            Name1: <input type="text" name="fname" value="ABC"><br>
            Name2: <input type="text" name="lname" value="123"><br>
        </form>
        <br />
        <img src="/images/arrow_left.jpg"  alt="left">
        <img src="/images/arrow_right.jpg" alt="right">
        <img src="/images/arrow_up.jpg"    alt="up">
        <img src="/images/arrow_down.jpg"  alt="down">
        <br/>
    </form>
</body>
<br/>
</html>
```

When I do a Refresh on this web page, I expect to see a single GET request, but i see multiple GET requests (one for the main page and one for ea image file). 
like this:

```
7 10.738337   163.64.287.173         10.235.5.146          HTTP     GET /mdg/HTML/FileUpload/Andy/multipart-form-data.html HTTP/1.1

9 10.739553   10.235.5.146          163.64.287.173         HTTP     HTTP/1.1 200 OK (text/html)

Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="multipart/form-data; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>

17 12.945487   163.64.287.173         10.225.57.136          HTTP     GET /images/arrow_left.jpg HTTP/1.1

19 12.946704   10.225.57.136          163.64.287.173         HTTP     HTTP/1.1 200 OK (JPEG JFIF image)

Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n

28 14.816313   163.64.287.173         10.225.57.136          HTTP     GET /images/arrow_right.jpg HTTP/1.1

30 14.817529   10.225.57.136          163.64.287.173         HTTP     HTTP/1.1 200 OK (JPEG JFIF image)

Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n

41 17.196125   163.64.287.173         10.225.57.136          HTTP     GET /images/arrow_up.jpg HTTP/1.1

43 17.197342   10.235.5.146          163.64.287.173         HTTP     HTTP/1.1 200 OK (JPEG JFIF image)

Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n

51 19.060141   163.64.287.173         10.225.57.136          HTTP     GET /images/arrow_down.jpg HTTP/1.1

53 19.061358   10.225.57.136          163.64.287.173         HTTP     HTTP/1.1 200 OK (JPEG JFIF image)

Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n
```

I expected to see 1 get request followed by several OK/CONTINUATION messages (with 'boundary=' data).
Something like this (from another web site):

`901 15:36:40.100491 10.277.7.10           72.253.197.19          HTTP     GET /app/WT/default.aspx?vtbl=1&debugds=320&vzmw3=vzmw3 HTTP/1.1`

```
903 15:36:40.317813 72.253.197.19          10.277.7.10           HTTP     HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=next.part.8412f441-e4ea-4554-8400-9a003df2f78f\r\n

Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=next.part.8412f441-e4ea-4554-8400-9a003df2f78f\r\n

MIME Multipart Media Encapsulation, Type: multipart/mixed, Boundary: "next.part.8412f441-e4ea-4554-8400-9a003df2f78f"

First boundary: --next.part.8412f441-e4ea-4554-8400-9a003df2f78f\r\n

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n

905 15:36:40.319315 63.64.187.229         97.253.137.46         HTTP     HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=next.part.8412f441-e4ea-4554-8400-9a003df2f78f\r\n

Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=next.part.8412f441-e4ea-4554-8400-9a003df2f78f\r\n

906 15:36:40.320116 72.253.197.19          10.247.7.10           HTTP     Continuation
```

Comment: How do you expect it to download the images without sending GET requests for them?

Comment: Multipart MIME types only make sense for email, not web pages.

Comment: This only testing whether multipart causes 1 GET request or several GET requests when the page is loaded/refreshed.
All desktop browsers ignore multipart and send several GET requests when loading the page.  However, I have an older Brew flip phone, and this phone supports multipart/form-data, so I would expect 1 GET requests with 1 or more continuation (200) responses from the server.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. Your document doesn't have multiple parts, that doesn't even make sense for HTML.

Comment: It has a <form> within a <form>.  The outer <form> hasenctype="multipart/form-data",the inner form has enctype="multipart/text/plain".  I expect the server to send fully encapsulated data in the HTTP Continuation responses (as detailed in the 2nd set of cap messages).  My issue is that for some reason, the server does not honor my 'enctype' when I say multipart/form-data or multipart/related.

Comment: `enctype` controls how the client sends the form fields to the server, it has nothing to do with how the server sends the web page to the client.

Comment: Mime multipart is commonly used by email, but has a significant usage when parsing HTML code.  (see this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)

Comment: If the browser supports MIME multipart, the GET request sent when loading/refreshing the web page, includes an "Accept" header that has 'multipart/mixed' or 'multipart/related', indicating that the browser supports multipart MIME.

Comment: The server then sends an HTTP OK, with Content-Type = "multipart/mixed”, followed by several HTTP Continuation packets that provide the HTML code as well as the encoded data for any <img> files.

Comment: Here's the flow:
Browser ==> Server ... Browser sends a Get request to the Server
                          The “Accept:” field has 
           "multipart/mixed"
           "multipart/related"

Comment: Server ==> Browser ... Server returns an HTTP 200 OK
                          The “Content-Type:" has
              "multipart/mixed”

Comment: Server ==> Browser ... Server sends an HTTP Continuation
                          The packet contains 
           the encoded data
        with ‘boundary’ records

Comment: Server ==> Browser ... Server sends the last HTTP Continuation packets.

Comment: Please don't put an essay in the comments, update your question if you have something to say. Anyway, as you can tell from what you've written, this is a browser feature, not something you put in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this in HTML. `Content-Type: multipart/...` is an HTTP header, whereas the HTML tag `<meta http-equiv="content-type">` supports very limited values as defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.http-equiv.content-type.html#meta.http-equiv.content-type

> A specially formatted string providing a character encoding name. Value: The
>   following parts, in exactly the following order:
>
> 1. The literal string "`text/html;`".
> 2. Optionally, one or more space characters.
> 3. The literal string "`charset=`".
> 4. One of the following:
>
>    - For documents in the HTML syntax: A character encoding name.
>    - For documents in the XML syntax: Any case-insensitive match for the string "`UTF-8`".

In other words, since this is an HTML document, the only allowed content-type is "text/html".

You want to specify "multipart/mixed" in the HTTP headers on the server side (e.g. using PHP header() or similar). But even then, it looks like the only browsers that support it are/were Firefox/Netscape; see [How to download multiple files with one HTTP request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041542/how-to-download-multiple-files-with-one-http-request)