# Javascript Plugin, Extplorer - Download Multiple Files at Once

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, download

I inherited a PHP program that allows users to download daily PDF/TIFF files onto their machine using the PHP/Javascript Extplorer plugin. Currently the files are downloaded individually by selecting the file and then downloading the file. This has become somewhat tedious for some customers who would like to select a set amount of files and then click download to collect them all at once. Is there a way to do so?

You can select multiple files by the well known Ctrl + Click; however, when you click download it only retrieves the first file that was selected.

I have dug into application.js.php and found where certain options are disabled or enabled based on the file selection count but cannot seem to grasp as to why only the first one is downloaded for selections greater than one.

Thank you in advance for your efforts.

Edit: Almost 2 weeks later, has anyone ever worked with the Extplorer plugin and or know of a solution if any? Thanks.

Comment: I've seen this before with other types of web based file explorers. For instance, Dropbox will only let you download a single file at a time.  However, they will let you download a zip file of all the selected files.
See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041542/how-to-download-multiple-files-with-one-http-request

Comment: @mcordaro - Thank you very much for your reply. I see now what you are talking about and it looks like Extplorer allows the same through an 'archive' option. The option only allows for the full folder instead of choosing which files you want. This could definitely work for the customers in my eyes; however, it looks like they would need write permissions to the folders because it creates a 'temp' folder to drop the zip in. This is still kind of a theory as google and no Extplorer documentation have been no help lol. I will try to look more into it.
Thanks a lot for your help, I apprecite it!