# Laravel how to download files with Response?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

is it possible to download more than one file?

One file is correct working, but how to download two files?

```
return response()->download('file.pdf');
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware Laravel's (and actually Symfony's) Response classes cannot handle multiple forced downloads.

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is about forcing an HTTP download *to* the browser, not accepting an upload *from* the browser.

Comment: @alexrussell Good point

Comment: try to execute the action twice, thus giving you two responses, meaning two separate downloads.

Comment: @AlexAndrei that doesn't work (and not because of Laravel - it's just not how HTTP works). Your best option is to either: open a few iframes or pop-ups for the user, OR give the user links for each file, OR zip the files and send the zip.

Comment: @samlev you are right, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a answer post for multiple files downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041542/how-to-download-multiple-files-with-one-http-request)

Zipping is the only option that will have consistent result on all browsers. If it's not an option because you don't know zips can be generated dynamically, well, they can. If it's not an option because you have a grudge against zip files, well..

MIME/multipart is for email messages and/or POST transmission to the HTTP server. It was never intended to be received and parsed on the client side of a HTTP transaction. Some browsers do implement it, some others don't.

As another alternative, you could have a JavaScript script opening windows downloading the individual files. Or a Java Applet (requires Java Runtimes on the machines, if it's an enterprise application, that shouldn't be a problem [as the NetAdmin can deploy it on the workstations]) that would download the files in a directory of the user's choice.