# how to return multiple zip files from asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to return multiple zip files  from web API  . I don't want to return all file in one zip file. I want to get all files in single request.  please help me how can i do that in asp.net web API

Comment: add what you have tried till now by editing the description.

Comment: Not sure what you want but I'm afraid you cant "download" multiple files in a single request. Each request can download one zip file. What if you return all the zip files download links and them download all of them separately?

Answer (score 0):

[This anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041591/957160) might give you an idea how to implement this.
It is either zip all files together or use JavaScript to open multiple windows for each download.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MIME `multipart/mixed` to return multiple files in a single request.

You have to implement a custom `MediaTypeFormatter` to make this work, how you do that is up to you.

The specifications for are available [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)