# Java OutputStream : Download Multiple Files

Tags: java, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I am trying to download multiple files using `OutputStream`. I have created a for loop, looping through a Vector `FileS` which has file names and download them. But only the first file is getting downloaded. My `Vector` has `FileZero.xml` at 0 and `FileOne.xml` at 1 and only fileZero is getting downloaded. Please help; here's my code

```
        for (int x = 0; x < FileS.size(); x++) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            reportFile = rm.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/folder/" + FileS.elementAt(x));
            try {
                while ((nRead = reportFile.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                    buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        buffer.flush();
        byte[] byteArray = buffer.toByteArray();

        try {

            byte bytes[] = null;
            bytes = byteArray;
            response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
            response.setContentType("application/force-download");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + FileS.elementAt(x));
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(bytes);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, I tried commenting out `out.flush()` and `out.close()`;but it didn't help. I tried putting the `OutputStream` object outside the loop just to test that also didn't help.

Comment: Don't you get any exception?

Comment: No exceptions . i ran the code in debug it goes through each step normally

Answer (score 2):

Closing the output stream (on first iteration) and then trying to write to it (on the second one) is of course an error.

But even if you comment out `out.close(), there is a problem: you set`Content-Length` twice with lengths of individual files, but you output both files content, so the length must be the sum of the individual lengths.

Looks like you are trying to download both files in one request. The only reliable way is to pack them both into a single archive (like a ZIP archive) and download one file, see here: [How to download multiple files with one HTTP request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041542/how-to-download-multiple-files-with-one-http-request)

Or just download them one by one.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense but the link that you provided also gives an idea not a real solution on how to create zip file with multiple files inside. Thanks though