# I want to make a server that returns text and image at the same time, only using python socket and not using modules like simplehttpserver

Tags: html, serversocket, python-sockets

Problem is that I cannot get my image files

1. Should I encode image files to binaryarras?
2. How can I put use utf-8 and base64 at the same time to make image and text show up at the same time...

   ```
   ##
   import socket
   import base64

   server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

   server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8080))

   server_socket.listen(1)
   print('listening')

   while True:
       connect_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
       data = connect_socket.recv(99999)

       print('data received : ',data.decode())

       connect_socket.sendall("""HTTP/1.1 200 OK

       <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8" />
           <title>Happy pig</title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <font color=#55C0F1 size=10>
          <h1>
               "Hi"
               <img src="pig.jpg" width= "137" height="150">
          </h1>
          </font>
       </form>
       </body>
       </html>""".encode('utf-8'))

   connect_socket.close()

   ##
   ```

Comment: It seems [multipart responses are not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041591/189018)