# Django, a problem about zip file response

Tags: python, django, zip

I have a problem with sending request as attachments in django. My application writes some data to files and zips it. However, when i return an attachment response, the browser downloads it but the zip file is corrupted. (The original zip contains my files and doesn't give any errors.)

My code is here:

```
        file_path = "/root/Programs/media/statics/schedules/"
        zip_file_name = file_path + "test.zip"
        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, "w")
        for i in range(len(planner_list)):
                file_name = file_path + str(planner_list[i][0].start_date)
                render_to_file('deneme.html',file_name ,{'schedule':schedule})
                zip_file.write(file_name, os.path.basename(file_name),zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
                os.remove(file_name)
        zip_file.close()

        response = HttpResponse(file_path , content_type='application/zip')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=test.zip'
        return response
```

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454/serving-dynamically-generated-zip-archives-in-django

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HttpResponse takes a string or an iterator returning strings (like an open file-like object). You are passing it the file path, so the response contains a file whose content is just the file path instead of the valid zip content you wrote to the file. You can just use `open` as the `HTTPResponse` object will close the file for you:

```
response = HttpResponse(open(file_path, 'rb'), content_type='application/zip')
```

Quoting the docs:

> Finally, you can pass HttpResponse an iterator rather than strings. HttpResponse will consume the iterator immediately, store its content as a string, and discard it. Objects with a close() method such as files and generators are immediately closed.
>
> If you need the response to be streamed from the iterator to the client, you must use the StreamingHttpResponse class instead.

Writing to disk on every request may hurt your server I/O - looking at your code, everything seems small enough to fit memory. You can use (C)StringIO (BytesIO in Python3) instead of real files:

```
from io import BytesIO

mem_file = BytesIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(mem_file, "w") as zip_file:
    for i, planner in enumerate(planner_list):
        file_name = str(planner[0].start_date)
        content = render_to_string('deneme.html', {'schedule':schedule})
    zip_file.writestr(file_name, content)

f.seek(0)  # rewind file pointer just in case
response = HttpResponse(f, content_type='application/zip')
```