# Python/Django: Offering a zip file for download from io.BytesIO buffer

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to put a zip file into an io.BytesIO buffer and then offer that for download. Below is what I've got (part of a longer views.py, I'm just posting the relevant part).

*But I'm getting the following error message:*

```
AttributeError at 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

**Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper
from zipfile import *
import io

buffer = io.BytesIO()

zipf = ZipFile(buffer, "w")
zipf.write ("file.txt")
zipf.close()

response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(buffer.getvalue()), content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.zip'

return response
```

***Edit:*** It's telling me the error is coming from the line:

```
response = HttpResponse(FileWrapper(buffer.getvalue()), content_type='application/zip')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the file in **byte mode** ('b')

try Changing

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()
zipf = ZipFile(buffer, "w")
zipf.write ("file.txt")
zipf.close()
```

to

```
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile("hello.zip", "w")
zipf.write("file.txt")
zipf.close()
response = HttpResponse(io.open("hello.zip", mode="rb").read(), content_type='application/zip')
```

Comment: It's telling me "ZipFile requires mode 'r', 'w', 'x', or 'a'"

Comment: From the docs it looks like you cannot write a buffer to zipfile module object

Comment: The ZIP file format is a common archive and compression standard. This module provides tools to create, read, write, append, and list a ZIP file. Any advanced use of this module will require an understanding of the format, as defined in PKZIP Application Note.This module does not currently handle multi-disk ZIP files. It can handle ZIP files that use the ZIP64 extensions (that is ZIP files that are more than 4 GiB in size). It supports decryption of encrypted files in ZIP archives, but it currently cannot create an encrypted file.

Comment: No, I'm trying to put a zip file in a buffer.

Answer (score 6):

I know this thread is a bit old, but still.

The `getvalue()` method of the BytesIO object returns the content in bytes which can be passed in to the `HttpResponse` with `content_type='application/zip'`.

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()
zipf = ZipFile(buffer, "w")
zipf.write ("file.txt")
zipf.close()
response = HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), content_type='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.zip'
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the file in memory and then sending it as a zip, I just saved the file onto the server and then sent it by following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510352/django-a-problem-about-zip-file-response).