# Create zip archive with multiple files

Tags: python

I'm using following code where I pass .pdf file names with their paths to create zip file.

```
for f in lstFileNames:
        with zipfile.ZipFile('reportDir' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.zip', 'w') as myzip:
            myzip.write(f)
```

It only archives one file though. **I need to archive all files in my list in one single zip folder.**

Before people start to point out, yes I have consulted answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881294/django-create-a-zip-of-multiple-files-and-make-it-downloadable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454/serving-dynamically-generated-zip-archives-in-django) link but the code given there doesn't work for me. The code runs but I can't find generated zip file anywhere in my computer.

A simple straightforward answer would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Order is incorrect. You are creating new zipfile object for each item in `lstFileNames`

Should be like this.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('reportDir' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.zip', 'w') as myzip:
    for f in lstFileNames:   
        myzip.write(f)
```

Comment: well, damn. It was as simple as that. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Isn't `myzip.close()` redundant inside context manager? It should be closed automagically after exited "with" statement section.

Comment: @Hunter_71 yes, it was recently added by someone else

Comment: Nice this answer came in handy for me, thanks @SardorbekImomaliev

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I have used this suggestion, but for reason it is creating a zipfile with folders/folder/folder/files. Is there anyway to simply create a zip with files?

Comment: @HelenNeely I suggest you create separate question for this and paste your code, it is probably related on how you generate list of filenames for archive

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with help from sample code solution to someone else's question :)