# How to send zip file in httpresponse attachment in python

Tags: python, django

I am making a jquery ajax POST request and passing the data to backend python code in Django framework. I need to return the zip file as httpresponse which should be automatically downloaded in browser.

```
             object_body = request.body.decode('utf-8')
             loaded_json = json.loads(object_body)

             json_obj = ast.literal_eval(str(loaded_json))

             zip_file_path = importexport.download(json_obj,user)
             zip_filename = os.path.basename(zip_file_path)

             with open(zip_file_path, 'rb') as zip:
               response = HttpResponse(zip.read(), content_type = 'application/x-zip')
               response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + zip_filename

             return response
```

Comment: Great question, what does your code result into so far? Do you get an error or do you not get an attachment?

Comment: Currently what you've got? Any response? any output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881294/django-create-a-zip-of-multiple-files-and-make-it-downloadable check it,

Comment: The file is not getting downloaded as attachement. In Response, its displaying the zip file contents

Comment: This is the ajax request being passed ....return $.ajax({
                url: "/testmgr/importexport/",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'application/x-zip', 
                accepts: 'application/x-zip',
                success: function(response) {
                },
            });

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

*put the zip file into MEDIA_ROOT, and redirect to the url of it.*

Answer (score 0):

If you have download URL (put the file into MEDIA_ROOT), you can just write `a` tag with `download` attribute and then click on Download as mentioned in following code snippet, it automatically downloads the file without redirection.

```html
<a href="https://github.com/vaibhavmule/vaibhavmule.github.io/archive/master.zip" download>Download</a>
```