# How to create a zip with multiple files from one folder and send it to the browser in modern Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-4.0

I was struggling with sending the downloadable Django zip with many files to browser, because many tutorials in the web are obsolete, like the one which was my inspiration to come up with what I will share with you:

[Django - Create A Zip of Multiple Files and Make It Downloadable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881294/django-create-a-zip-of-multiple-files-and-make-it-downloadable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THE SOLUTION

We're not using many functions in this projects but rather blocks of code with docstrings, but you can easily pack this code into a function:

```
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

from django.http import HttpResponse

#get the name of the folder you want to download from the frontend using input
directory_name = request.POST["folder"]

#create the zip file
file_blueprint = BytesIO()
zip_file = ZipFile(file_blueprint, 'a')

#create the full path to the folder you want to download the files from
directory_path = BASE_PATH + directory_name

for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
    try:
    #characterize the from path and the destination path as first and second argument
        zip_file.write(os.path.join(directory_path + "/" + filename), os.path.join(directory_name + "/" + filename))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
zip_file.close()

#define the the zip file as a response
response = HttpResponse(file_blueprint.getvalue(), content_type = "application/x-zip-compressed")
response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename= your-zip-folder-name.zip"

return response
```