# Serving Zip file Django

Tags: django

I'm following this solution ([Serving dynamically generated ZIP archives in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454/serving-dynamically-generated-zip-archives-in-django)) to serve some zip files from django.

The idea is to select the files from a database using some check boxes,  but I'm trying to make the example work with just 2 images.

```
import os
import zipfile
import StringIO

from django.http import HttpResponse


def getfiles(request):
    # Files (local path) to put in the .zip
    # FIXME: Change this (get paths from DB etc)
    filenames = ["/home/../image1.png", "/home/../image2.png"]

    # Folder name in ZIP archive which contains the above files
    # E.g [thearchive.zip]/somefiles/file2.txt
    # FIXME: Set this to something better
    zip_subdir = "somefiles"
    zip_filename = "%s.zip" % zip_subdir

    # Open StringIO to grab in-memory ZIP contents
    s = StringIO.StringIO()

    # The zip compressor
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(s, "w")

    for fpath in filenames:
        # Calculate path for file in zip
        fdir, fname = os.path.split(fpath)
        zip_path = os.path.join(zip_subdir, fname)

        # Add file, at correct path
        zf.write(fpath, zip_path)

    # Must close zip for all contents to be written
    zf.close()

    # Grab ZIP file from in-memory, make response with correct MIME-type
    resp = HttpResponse(s.getvalue(), mimetype = "application/x-zip-compressed")
    # ..and correct content-disposition
    resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % zip_filename

    return resp
```

I wrote the getfile(request)  on my views.py   and i make a call from the index view

```
def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':  # If the form has been submitted...
        resp = getfiles(request)
        form = FilterForm(request.POST)  # A form bound to the POST data
        # do some validation and get latest_events from database

    context = {'latest_events_list': latest_events_list, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'db_interface/index.html', context)
```

I know the getfile() method is called, because if I put names of unexistents files I got an error,  but I dont get any download neither an error if the filenames are correct (I put the full path /home/myuser/xxx/yyy/Project/app/static/app/image1.png).

I tried with the django server and with  the  apache2/nginx server I have for production

I also tried using `content_type = 'application/force-download'`

Thanks

Comment: This code just discards `resp` after calculating it. Where do you plan to actually return a response containing the zip file to the user?

Comment: In the index, after submitting the form I want to get the file for download and reload the same  index.html

Comment: Step one will be to set up a URL that serves the zip file. I believe you'd then have to use Javascript to trigger downloading it upon loading the page after form submission. Base HTTP does not do mixed HTML and file downloads in a single response.

Comment: perfect, I set up an url directly to views.getfile and it works