# How can I dynamically generate a zip file and save it on my drive in django

Tags: django, zip

I have used this to serve the file directly for download [Serving dynamically generated ZIP archives in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454/serving-dynamically-generated-zip-archives-in-django). But, I want to save that zip file in a directory.

Thank You.

Comment: How? You mean in a directory on client side?

Comment: nope, on my server itself

Comment: Well, you can just write to a file as in documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile