# Python create zip file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I use the following script to create ZIP files:

```
import zipfile
import os

def zip_file_generator(filenames, size):

    # filenames = path to the files

    zip_subdir = "SubDirName"
    zip_filename = "SomeName.zip"

    # Open BytesIO to grab in-memory ZIP contents
    s = io.BytesIO()

    # The zip compressor
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(s, "w")

    for fpath in filenames:
        # Calculate path for file in zip
        fdir, fname = os.path.split(fpath)
        zip_path = os.path.join(zip_subdir, fname)

        # Add file, at correct path
        zf.write(fpath, zip_path)

    # Must close zip for all contents to be written
    zf.close()

    # Grab ZIP file from in-memory, make response with correct MIME-type
    resp = HttpResponse(s.getvalue(), content_type = "application/x-zip-compressed")
    # ..and correct content-disposition
    resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % zip_filename
    resp['Content-length'] = size

    return resp
```

I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12951461/5123800).

But I changed `s = StringIO.StringIO()` to `s = io.BytesIO()` because I am using Python 3.x.

The zip file does get created with the right size etc. But I can't open it. It is invalid. If I write the zip file to disk the zip file is valid.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I am sorry. I don't understand your question

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: gaba is trying to write the zip data to `s`.

Comment: Weird. I just tested the zip part of your code (on Python 2.6.6), writing `s.getvalue()` as a binary file to disk and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working. Just change size in `resp['Content-length'] = size` to `s.tell()`

Comment: Now it makes sense. Yes, 'Content-length' needs to be the size of the actual data you're sending, not the size before compression.

Comment: I'm sorry, but for me it's not working. The zip file has content but I cannot unzip it

Answer (score 1):

I use shutil to zip like so:

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive(archive_name, '.zip', folder_name)
```