# Stream multiple HTTP file requests into a zipped response stream in Django

Tags: python, django, zip

My question is similar in nature to [this very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12951461/2921041), but I want to stream in and out simultaneously.

I have a django app that stores references to files on an external http fileserver. Right now when a user requests a zip collection it does the following (pseudo):

```
generate session_id
for url in url_list:
    download file to sessionid/filename.ext
for file in session_id folder:
    zip.write
close
http response
```

Obviously this is less than ideal as it: 1. Requires cleanup, 2. Is slow and 3. causes a long delay before the user sees any download progress.

The bit I'm unable to re-code is the io buffer/"file like object". Zipfile looks for a file on write but I want to provide a stream. In brief, how can I pipe `requests` to `zipfile` to `HttpResponse`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the writestr command with a streaming file download, I recommend the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests).

[Zipfile.writestr Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html)

```
ZipFile.writestr(zinfo_or_arcname, bytes[, compress_type])
```

Edit: Sample

```
zipinfo = ...
zip = ...

for url in list:
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        # filter out keep-alive new lines
        if line:
            print(zip.writestr(zipinfo, line))
```

Comment: Looks like this probably has me sorted. Was trying to stream it to StringIO instead of BytesIO. I'll mark as answer in a minute all going to plan.

Comment: @Linef4ult did this answer help you?