# How to export zip in django admin?

Tags: python, django

I have images fields in my model. How to I can export to zip from my django admin. Here is my code

```
from django.db import models


class ModelWithImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images',
    )
```

Admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ModelWithImage

admin.site.register(ModelWithImage)
```

Comment: Where is your admin.py code? You've posted only your models.py.

Comment: Please check the question again!

Comment: Is it possiable?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is used to create zipfile for content in files (path) in `filenames`.

```py
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip')
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(response, 'w')
for filename in filenames:
    zip_file.write(filename)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(zipfile_name)
return response
```

This code is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49220016/10088534), you may have a look for better understanding.
Although I think above code should solve your problem.

Comment: Can you share that? How I can integrate with models?